# Program crashes because of a While loop

Tags: c++, qt

I am making a simple desktop app because i am learning Qt.
I want to make a button where if you press it it starts a while loop until you press it again.

Here is my basic code:

```
void TestApp::on_pushButton_3_toggled(bool checked)
{
    if (checked) {
        ui->status_label->setText("Status: Testing!");
        while (true) {
            qDebug() <<"Test";
        }
    } else {
        ui->status_label->setText("Status: Working!");
    }
}
```

The program works fine when i press the button to enable it. But it crashes when i try to disable it because of the while loop.

How can i fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you think `while (true) {` does? What do you intend to do with this construct?

Comment: You have an infinite loop that will never end, what's the purpose of it?

Comment: As for the "crash", since your loop will never end the program will never get back to the UI event loop, and as such the program will become totally unresponsive. On Windows that means your program will not respond to any events, not even requests to close or terminate the program in a nice way, so Windows will simply kill the program, which could look like a crash.

Comment: It does not actually crash, it's just that your UI has no chance to update because of your infinite loop. Modern windows will detect that the UI is not responding and popup a dialog notifying you about the unresponsive application and allowing you to kill it.

Answer (score 6):

Let me briefly explain how a Qt application works. When you call [`exec()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#exec) of the [`QGuiApplication`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html) or [`QCoreApplication`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html), Qt will start its own main event loop.
In that event loop, various events from external events or internal events would be queued to process. This will include mouse/keyboard events, window events, signal/slot events and etc.
When you call `while(true){ ... }` your code will never return to the Qt's event loop and it simply becomes unresponsive. You can interpret `while(true){}` as **forever**.
So, if you want to run `qDebug() <<"Test";` while the button is `checked`, you can simply start a [`QTimer`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html) by calling start(500) on it or stop() it when `checked` is false.
Then you can have the `timeout()` signal of that [`QTimer`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html) connected to a lambda function or a member function to print out "Test" string using `qDebug()`.

```
void TestApp::aFuncToCreateConnection(){ // this could be the constructor

    connect(ui->some_timer, &QTimer::timeout, [](){qDebug() << "Test" } );
}
void TestApp::on_pushButton_3_toggled(bool checked)
{
    if (checked) {
        ui->status_label->setText("Status: Testing!");
        ui->some_timer->start(500);
    } else {
        ui->status_label->setText("Status: Working!");
        ui->some_timer->stop();
    }
}
```

You should create a [`QTimer`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html) instance with the name of `some_timer` in your `UI`.
You can learn more about Qt's signal/slot syntax [here](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax).